# Avoid long-tap behaviour on mobile devices while pressing a button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

In my HTML there is a button that can be short- and long-clicked. If you click on it shortly (like on every other button) it executes a given callback function. When you keep pressing the button the callback will be repeatedly executed until a mouseup or mouseout event is detected.

```
var onBtnClick = function (evt, callback) {
        //only react to left mouse button
        if (evt.which == 1) {
            //save 'this' context and interval/timeout IDs
            var self    = this,
                interval= null,
                timeout = null;

            //react to a single click
            callback();

            //when user leaves the button cancel timeout/interval, lose focus and unbind recently bound listeners
            self.on("mouseup mouseout", function () {
                window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                self.blur();
                self.off("mouseup mouseout");
            });

            //on a long click call the callback function within an interval for faster value changing
            timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
                interval = window.setInterval(callback, 50);
            }, 300);
        }
    },

    i = 0,

    cb = function () {
        console.log(i++);
    };

$("button").mousedown(function(evt) {
    onBtnClick.call($(this), evt, cb);
});
```

This works fine on desktop environments. BUT: When using the website on a mobile device the long click wont be registered as the browser detects a right-click (long-tap).

**Is it possible to recreate the behaviour from desktop on a mobile device? How could I achieve this?**

Comment: Make sure the callback is triggered only once!

Comment: @LShetty: But I want to trigger the callback as long as the user keeps the button pressed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to include `touchstart` and `touchend` events for mobile. Additionally, you're going to want to make sure the functions you give for them includes a call to `evt.preventDefault()`. Doing this effectively tells the mobile browser "Hey, you know that thing you normally want to do right now? Don't do that."

That said, an updated version of the code you provided should look like this:

```
var onBtnClick = function (evt, callback) {
        //only react to left mouse button or a touch event
        if (evt.which == 1 || evt.type == "touchstart") {
            //save 'this' context and interval/timeout IDs
            var self    = this,
                interval= null,
                timeout = null;

            //react to a single click
            callback();

            //when user leaves the button cancel timeout/interval, lose focus and unbind recently bound listeners
            self.on("mouseup mouseout touchend", function (evt) {
                window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                self.blur();
                self.off("mouseup mouseout touchend");
                evt.preventDefault();
            });

            //on a long click call the callback function within an interval for faster value changing
            timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
                interval = window.setInterval(callback, 50);
            }, 300);
        }
    },

    i = 0,

    cb = function () {
        console.log(i++);
    };

$("button").mousedown(function(evt) {
    onBtnClick.call($(this), evt, cb);
});

$('#hold').on('touchstart', function (evt) {
    onBtnClick.call($(this), evt, cb);
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Key changes: Added `|| evt.type == "touchstart"` to the if check so that you capture both left mouse button and touch events, added `touchend` to the list of `mouseup` and `mouseout` events, added `evt.preventDefault()` to the function that clears your timeouts, and added an `on('touchstart'` jQuery call to ensure your button is actually listening specifically for touches as well as clicks.

Comment: That's it. Thank you! I tried using `evt.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;` and this works fine for me as well.

Comment: I actually completely forgot `preventDefault` was a thing. That's most likely the better way to handle it; I'll update the answer to match.

Comment: I tested that a bit and now on Windows Phone with mobile IE I have another problem. Avoiding the context menu works fine but if I keep the button pressed the callback is only called like 12 times and then stops (like I have stopped pressing). I have to press again to get another 12 steps and so on. What's wrong here, why does the callback not get called as long as I keep the button pressed?